# Value labels (levels) are lost when modifing a memisc:data.set in R

Tags: r

I use `memisc:data.set` because I import data from SPSS. I can get the value labels (in SPSS meaning) from a object when asking for `levels()`. I use that for the labels of the tick-marks in a plot.

When I modify the `data.set` (like in the exmpale below) `levels()` doesn't work anymore.

```
library('memisc')
# example dta
d <- data.set(a = sample(1:100))
d$a_strat <- cut(d$a, breaks=seq(1,100, by=10))

# "modify" the data.set
e <- d[,c('a_strat')]

# it is still a data.set but "a_strat" changed it's type
> class(e)
[1] "data.set"
attr(,"package")
[1] "memisc"
```

Now have a look at the different data types of `a_strat` in the two `data.set`.

```
> str(d$a_strat)
 Factor w/ 9 levels "(1,11]","(11,21]",..: 4 9 3 1 NA 9 5 4 9 9 ...
> str(e$a_strat)
 $ Nmnl. item w/ 9 labels for 1,2,3,...  int  4 9 3 1 NA 9 5 4 9 9 ...
```

The practical issue is I can not do that on the second `data.set`.

```
> levels(e$a_strat)
NULL
```

But this works

```
> labels(e$a_strat)

 Values and labels:

   1 '(1,11]' 
   2 '(11,21]'
   3 '(21,31]'
   4 '(31,41]'
   5 '(41,51]'
   6 '(51,61]'
   7 '(61,71]'
   8 '(71,81]'
   9 '(81,91]'
```

But when I use that for plotting in `axis(..., labels=labels(e$_strat))` the value labels (e.g. `(32,41]`) doesn't appear. Instead of that the values (`1`, `2`, ..., `9`) appear on the tickmarks.

I am not sure how to solve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The little helper here is `as.factor()`.
So it could look like this

```
axis(..., labels=labels(as.factor(e$_strat)))
```

But please don't rate that answer positive. ;) I still can't understand why the *type* of `a_strat` changes in my example.